# How does callback way of asynchronous programming ensures that the callback function is run only after doing the asynchronous task?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Say, I have to do a asynchronous task (an AJAX call) and then run my callback function. The callback way of coding I've seen on the web so far is:

```
const myAsynchronousFunction = (data, callback) => {
  ajaxCall(data);
  callback();
}
```

Does this function ensures that the callback is executed after the ajax call? If not, how to? If yes, how does it ensures that the above code runs in a synchronous manner.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, this would be ran asynchronously. The `callback` will be executed before the ajaxCall would complete.

To ensure callback is ran after the ajax call, you could use `async await` like so:

```js
const myAsynchronousFunction = async (data, callback) => {
  await ajaxCall(data);
  callback();
}
```

Note the `async` and `await` keywords. This would ensure the `ajaxCall` promise completes before `callback` is executed.

Or, you could use `Promise.then()` syntax, which does the same thing:

```js
const myAsynchronousFunction = (data, callback) => {
  ajaxCall(data).then(() => callback())
}
```

When `ajaxCall` promise succeeds, it fires `then()`, which would then execute your `callback()`

Comment: Both ways provides a neater way of handling the asynchronous stuff, just curious..how it should've been done if we didn't want to use neither promises nor the async-await keywords. Just good ol' callbacks way.

Comment: If you're not doing any async stuff (such as network requests, anything that returns a promise), then simply having `callback()` at the bottom of your function will suffice. The callback function will be executed after the rest of the function has ran.

Comment: is there a way to run the callback only after the async task even if doesn't return a promise? (without using ```.then() ``` or ```async-await```)

Comment: I'm not sure how you would create an asynchronous task without using a promise... You would have to send an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: A function that doesn't returns me a promise object, say, ```setTimeout(someFunc, 4000)``` How to run a function (the callback) after this asynchronous function? In detail, I want to write a function that would take a some data(that is passed to my async func which will run inside the caller) and a callback. I have to write this function without using async await keywords and neither does my ```async task``` returns me a promise so that I can't use a ```.then()```.

Comment: Just like this: `setTimeout(function(){ callback(); }, 3000);`. All a callback is, is you are executing a function that has been passed as an argument. There shouldn't be any magic happening.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to call the callback inside of the ajax callback. The ajax callback function will only start running after the ajax request has finished. So add logic you want after the ajax inside of its' callback.

Comment: umm.. AJAX call was an example.. let's take a random asynchronous function say ```setTimeout(something, 4000)``` that doesn't take callbacks as arguments. How'd you run the callback function after the asynchronous task is completed?

Comment: @noobmaster69 setTime out takes callback as arguments, this is the thing. `setTimeout(HERE_IS_THE_CALLBACK, 4000)`. ANY asynchronous function has a callback, promise or observable. If not then it's designed wrongly and you should avoid using it.

Comment: @noobmaster69 It would help more if you told us your true use case.